# show modal dialog for list with opened ribbon

Tags: javascript, ribbon, modal-dialog

I need to display a standard list inside a modal dialog. Currently I'm using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(..) and I'm building the URL like this:

```
options.url = "listform.aspx?PageType=0&ListId={...list-guid...}&RootFolder=";
```

and it works great, but by default the ribbon is collapsed. The problem is - when the user clicks "Items" or "List" tabs, the ribbon shows up, but the dialog is not resizing according its new height, and ugly scrollbars show up.

Is there a way to open the dialog with the Ribbon opened by default ?

UPDATE:
I was able to get rid of the scrollbars when the ribbon is opened by overriding default "OnRibbonMinimizedChanged(minimizedRibbon)" handler and calling "autosize()" on a dialog. Details: [here](http://chadschroeder.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepoint-2010-easy-dynamic-resize-of.html). ...But it would still be nice to have an option of showing dialog with already opened Ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add one of these to your URL depending on which tab you want viewed:

&InitialTabID=Ribbon.List
&InitialTabID=Ribbon.ListItem // the item tab
&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read  // this is the browse tab, no ribbon.

Comment: Tried this solution. Did not work for me.